# Imageadapter and listview with image from json

Tags: android, image, listview

I have yet another question regarding displaying image on listview from json object. I checked almost every possible answers on stackoverflow but did not find any solution. I have following implementation

```
                contact = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACT);
                for(int i = 0; i < contact.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = contact.getJSONObject(i);
                    //put json obkject on variable
                    String fname = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String uname = c.getString(TAG_UNAME);
                    String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String thumb = c.getString(TAG_THUMB);
                    // Adding value HashMap key => value
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, fname);
                    map.put(TAG_UNAME, uname);
                    map.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
                    map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    map.put(TAG_THUMB, thumb);
                    contactlist.add(map);
                 // Finding the list view
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactlist);
                    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());



                 // Put data on listview content
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ContactPage.this, contactlist,
                            R.layout.contact_list,
                            new String[] {TAG_NAME,TAG_UNAME,TAG_TYPE,TAG_EMAIL,TAG_THUMB}, new int[] {
                                    R.id.contact_name,R.id.contact_usertype,R.id.contact_status,R.id.contact_email,R.id.contact_image});
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now where and how shall I implement the `imgLoader.DisplayImage(url, imageView)` in my code if I have image URL on thumb , i.e c.getString(TAG_THUMB);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I checked almost every possible answers on stackoverflow" I don't beleive you. It is very popular question on SO. Try to search 'android custom adapter'

Comment: Well I know it is pretty awkward to write,"almost every possible answer", might be i am not searching correct keyword. But I searched different posts and implement imgLoader.DislayImage... before putting data on list content. Unfortunately I got javanullPointer on the line.

Comment: Thanks Georgy , actually you are right. Thats why I love stackoverflow. I used LazyAdapter and it Solved my problem. Thanks a lot for guiding me with correct keyword.